# Modal won't close when clicking on background or pressing esc

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

On my site I have a Lightbox built in Bootstrap 4 with a modal that opens the image to see a larger version.
It all works well but the only way to close the Modal is by clicking the X at the top righthand screen.
I understood the default was that Modals would close when clicking the background and I would like help in getting this to work as it should please.

Thank you very much

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.40);
display: flex;
min-height: 100vh;
flex-direction: column;
}

#wrap {
flex: 1;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
h1 {font-family: omnes-pro,sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;}


h2 {font-family: omnes-pro,sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;}

ul {list-style: none;}
li {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;

}


.portfolio-title {
width: 100%;
border-bottom: rgba(255,255,255,1.00) thin solid;
}
.nav-link {
font-size: 130%
}



.image {width: 100%;}

.article {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;}




.frame {border: rgba(255,253,253,1.00) thin solid;}

#gallery {max-width: 95%;}

/* image gallery start */
.row {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
flex: 25%;
max-width: 25%;
padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
margin-top: 8px;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.column {
flex: 50%;
max-width: 50%;
}
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to       each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.column {
flex: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
.modal-content {
padding: 20;
width: 80%;
}
#mobilefirst {
border: rgba(255,253,253,1.00) thin solid;
margin-bottom: 10px;}
#gallery {border: none;}
}

/* image gallery stop */

/* modal start */

.row > .column {
padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to eachother */
.column {
float: left;
width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 200;
padding-top: 100px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 10;
width: 100%;
max-width: 663px;
max-height: 999px;
border: rgba(255,255,255,1.00) thin solid;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
font-size: 35px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the slides by default */
.mySlides {
display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
padding: 16px;
margin-top: -50px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
}


img.demo {
opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
-webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
-moz-transform: scale(0.1);
-ms-transform: scale(0.1);
transform: scale(0.1);
top: 300px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* modal stop */
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Lightbox</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/css/stylesheetlightbox.css" rel="stylesheet"      type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/edx4faj.css">
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrap">
<div class="container-fluid content-wrap">      
<div class="container mt-3 p-2 shadow-lg d-block d-sm-none"> <img   src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/images/logos/aytonwest-people_logo2018-white.png"   class="img-fluid" alt="Ayton West Logo"></div>

<div class="container">
<h1 class="p-3 text-center">Photographer of gardens and botanical studies</h1>
</div>

    
    <!-- image gallery start -->
    
<div class="container-fluid pt-3 pl-4 pr-4 shadow-lg mt-4 frame" id="gallery">
<div class="row"> 
<div class="column">
<img src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/images/portfolio-botanical/ayton-west- botanical-garden-01.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow" id="mobilefirst">
</div>
        
<div class="column">
<img src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/images/portfolio-botanical/ayton-west- botanical-garden-07.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow d-none  d-sm-block">
</div>
        
<div class="column">
<img src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/images/portfolio-botanical/ayton-west-botanical-garden-13.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow d-none d-sm-block">
</div>
        
<div class="column">
<img src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/images/portfolio-botanical/ayton-west-botanical-garden-19.jpg" alt="" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow d-none d-sm-block">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>  

<!-- image gallery stop -->
    

<!-- The Modal/Lightbox -->

<div id="myModal"  <div class="modal">
<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
<div class="modal-content">

<div class="mySlides">
<img src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/images/portfolio-botanical/ayton-west- botanical-garden-01.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
</div>

  
  <div class="mySlides">
  <img src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/images/portfolio-botanical/ayton-west- botanical-garden-07.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
  </div>
  
 
  <div class="mySlides">
  <img src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/images/portfolio-botanical/ayton-west-botanical-garden-13.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
  </div>
  


  <div class="mySlides">
  <img src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/images/portfolio-botanical/ayton-west-botanical-garden-19.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="">
  </div>
  


  
  
<!-- Next/previous controls -->
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>




</div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/js/popper.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.aytonwest.com/2021site/js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js"></script>
  
  <script>
// Open the Modal
function openModal() {
document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

// Close the Modal
function closeModal() {
document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}
      

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the keypress function in jQuery, you can address any key on the keyboard. In the example below, the website will alert you when you press `escape`. Instead of the alert you can add your own function.

Press **"Run code snippet"** and click in the **snippet** to **focus** the page on it. Then you have to press **"Escape"**.

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
       if (event.key == "Escape") {
           alert('You pressed Escape!');
       }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Click me and press Escape!</h1>
```

If you want the modal to close, you have to do it this way:

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
       if (event.key == "Escape") {
           closeModal();
       }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Add this jQuery Link and the JS-Code and the Modal will close when you press escape!</h1>
```

Comment: Would be kind enough to clarify? Im not certain I understand what it is you're suggesting. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't so clear. I'll edit the answer.